# Unable to properly create new Eclipse projects for Drools or Guvnor in Windows8 (Drools disappears and server options aren't displayed)

Tags: eclipse, windows-8, jboss, drools, drools-guvnor

I've installed Eclipse on two machines (one is running Windows 8 and the other has Mac OS X v.10.5.8), but it doesn't seem to be running correctly in Windows 8 as I'm experiencing two significant problems while setting up a new project.

1. When I use the wizard to *Define a New Server* in order to use Guvnor it only lists two *Basic Server Type* options *(HTTP Preview & HTTP Server)*, even once I've downloaded additional servers/server adapters.
2. Drools is running correctly for me until I set the runtime and restart Eclipse, when all the references to Drools vanish from the Eclipse workspace (including *Preferences, File -> New, Perspective*, or even as a result when I search in *'Quick Access'*).  It does however still showed Drools as installed (when I click on *'What is already installed?'*). I've tried reinstalling Drools, as well as manually unzipping it and adding it to the plugin folder, but it still isn't showing up in Eclipse.  In order to verify that Drools hadn't been corrupted, I created a 2nd instance of Eclipse on my desktop (where I repeated the plugin  installation process) with the exact same result.

I've installed both Apache (Apache HTTP Server 2.2.25) and JBoss Application Server 7 (EAP 6.1.0).  In addition, I've downloaded JBoss Tools 4.1  to address the potential issue raised in this post https://community.jboss.org/en/tools/blog/2013/10/08/update-to-jboss-tools-41-and-developer-studio-70

I'm running: Windows 8, Drools & Guvnor 6.0.0.CR4 and Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Version: Kepler Service Release 1, Build id: 20130919-0819

Comment: Well, I guess this site is wrong place to ask such questions. You might want, to do that on http://superuser.com/

Comment: @DaveJust - I was beginning to wonder ;-) I've never felt so unpopular on SO ;-) I wasn't familiar with superuser.com, but that's a good idea (and a wonderful resource) :-) Do you think that it's due to the nature of the question (setting up instead of coding a project)? Out of curiosity, do you think that I should first try rephrasing the title or offering a bounty (once it's eligible)?

Comment: Here on SO, people usually ask about **specific** questions about algorithms, best practices and the like. Your question definitely itself is about : how to *properly configure the thing*, which is kinda off-topic here. And that's the reason - it cannot be popular here. You'd better ask the same question on superuser.com and offer a bounty. That will help... :)

Comment: If you compare, http://stackoverflow.com/about and http://superuser.com/about then you'll get an idea where I'm coming from

Comment: @DaveJust - Thank you :-D In terms of protocol, do you think I'm better off referencing the answer when I get one or closing/deleting this post?

Comment: I guess you have nothing to lose if you leave this post as it is :) Who knows, maybe someone else would comment on this post..

Comment: @DaveJust :-D And thanks for pointing me in the right direction :-)

Comment: On Aug 29 there was a commit against issue `BZ-1001723 - Apply button resets default Drools runtime` that may be related with the issue you are describing. The issue is unfortunately private so I can't be sure.I would try latest SNAPSHOT to see if the error is solved there. Regards.

Comment: @EstebanAliverti - Good suggestion, but I don't believe that's the same issue because in my case it works perfectly on a Mac but on my Windows machine Drools itself is disappearing entirely from the Eclipse framework once I set runtime.